# Running wordpress as subdomain

Tags: wordpress, directory, subdomain, cpanel

I have a Wordpress website http://dominio.com which should be available via a subdomain (`nome.dominio.com`). All files are stored in a subfolder `dominio.com/file` of my main domain.

Server administration of my VPS is done using Vesta C Panel.

Could you please give me some help?
I thank's advance

Comment: You will usually do that from the Cpanel, first creating a subdomain and after targeting to the absolute folder in your server/hosting

Comment: Rewrite text to make it understandable. Added wordpress and cpanel tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the website on a subdomain, I would recommend to create the subdomain via the Cpanel, then to install or move the WordPress to the main subdomain directory.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I've written bad!

I wanted to say that now I have a Wordpress website (dominio.com)
Using VPS Server with Vesta CPanel
I should point to a sub domain (nome.dominio.com) to a subfolder (dominio.com/cartella)

Forgive me for the mistake, unfortunately I use the translator I do not write English well.

thanks for a new response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the sub-domain and point that sub-domain path to your subdirectory (dominio.com/file). And from wordpress database change the URLs. That's it.

It can help you more if you want [Moving Wordpress Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)